# Python list.append not working. I'm using discord.py and replit database to make a gambling bot and I wanted a list of participants

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

So basically I'm trying to get a discord betting bot to give a list of participants that it can cycle through when games end. The problem is that when I use this code it doesn't seem to append. I've tried debugging it using an alt. The not in db['list'] part triggers fine, and there are no errors raised, but the list still only contains my main account's ID (which was used to create the list.)

The repl.it database is basically a big array with string indexes / keys. I'm sure that lists are an accepted data type since when I debugged before it printed db['list'] as ['#MYIDNUMBER'] but it still won't append my alt's.

````
    db['list'] = [str(message.author.id)]
    db['betenable'] = True
  if message.content.startswith('$createaccount'):
    db[str(message.author.id)+'wallet'] = 1000
    db[str(message.author.id)+'ingame'] = 0
    db[str(message.author.id)+'bet'] = 'No Party'
    if str(message.author.id) not in db['list']:
      db['list'].append(str(message.author.id))```
````

Comment: did you mean `db['list']` instead of `db[list]`?

Comment: Yeah that was dumb of me. I changed it but it's still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working, does it raise an error is it doing something wrong, more information is required for the question to be answered

Comment: It does not raise an error, the if not in statement triggers, but the list doesn't have the new ID in it when I check.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing `db[list]`, using the `list` built-in, instead of the string, `db['list']`.

Comment: Strange. It's still not working after I edited it.

Comment: @JonesMalone what issue are you having now?

Comment: Same as before. No error is raised, the if not in statement triggers fine, but the list didn't have the new ID.

Comment: Hard to know why without seeing the full code, maybe you are overwriting the db somewhere after modifying it?

Comment: No, the statement ends there. Immediately after that I put a print(db['list']) but it only had one element.